# Finding the Remainder of $f(x)=(x-1)^2(x+2)Q(x)+R(x)$

Tags: problem-solving

So I'm a high school student and I'm stuck on a question. Please help.

$f(x)=(x-1)^2Q(x)+3x+1$

$f(x)=(x+2)Q(x)+4$

$f(x)=(x-1)^2(x+2)Q(x)+R(x)$

My first approach was Making $R(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, I soon found out that there are only two equations not three to find $a, b, c$

I don't understand how to solve this.

Comment: I guess it's not the same $Q(x)$ on the three lines? You should find a less confusing way to write it. Then remember where the extra equation would come from when the divisor has a double root.

Comment: Notice that $R(x) $ divided by $(x-1)^2$ leaves remainder $3x+1$ and dividing by $x+2$ leaves remainder $4$. That should help you to figure out $a, b, c$.

Comment: To expand on the comment from @dxiv: differentiate.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach.
$$f(x)=(x-1)^2Q_1(x)+3x+1 \tag 1 $$
$$f(x)=(x+2)Q_2(x)+4 \tag 2 $$
$$f(x)=(x-1)^2(x+2)Q_3(x)+R(x) \tag 3 $$
From (1) and (3), $(x-1)^2$ divides $R(x)-3x-1.$ Therefore,
$$R(x)=k(x-1)^2+3x+1 \tag 4$$
By (2), $f(-2)=4.$ By (4) and (3),
$$R(-2)=9k-6+1=f(-2)=4.$$
Thus, $k=1$ and
$$R(x)=x^2+x+2.$$